# Dividir código AngularJs en Controller y Service

Tags: angularjs

¿Alguien sabe como dividir éste código en controlador y Service? En el ejemplo http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/maqbzv15/1118/ están unidos pero estoy trabajando con Controllers y Services

```
//inject angular file upload directives and services.
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
    $scope.uploadPic = function(file) {
    file.upload = Upload.upload({
      url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
      data: {username: $scope.username, file: file},
    });

    file.upload.then(function (response) {
      $timeout(function () {
        file.result = response.data;
      });
    }, function (response) {
      if (response.status > 0)
        $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
    }, function (evt) {
      // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
      file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
    });
    }
}]);
```

Comment: quieres que `uploadPic` venga de un servicio? o es otra cosa? puedes acalarar bien como es que tiene que quedar.?. Gracias!!.

Comment: Se supone que ese controlador sube la imagen al servidor, pero subir la imagen al servidor es una función del service no del controlador, lo que quiero es que el controlador no suba el archivo sino que lo suba el service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes ver la ejecución en: http://jsfiddle.net/hectormosq/bfjm736r/1/

El servicio Upload utilizado es quien procesa la subida del archivo, sin embargo he desarrollado un servicio adicional (fileUploadService) que permite abstraer el procesamiento de respuesta del servicio de manera que únicamente se asigne la respuesta al controlador de forma mas limpia.

```
//inject angular file upload directives and services.
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);


app.service('fileUploadService', ['Upload', '$q', '$timeout', function (Upload, $q, $timeout) {
var service = {};

function fileUpload(file, username) {
    var defer = $q.defer();

    //La funcion ejecuta el servicio upload
    file.upload = Upload.upload({
        url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
        data: {username: username, file: file},
    });

    //.then procesamos la respuesta asincrona

    file.upload.then(
        //Siendo respuesta satisfactoria
        function (response) {
            $timeout(function () {
                defer.resolve(response.data);
            });
            //Error
        }, function (response) {
            if (response.status > 0)
                var errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            defer.reject(errorMsg);
            //Notificacion del estado del servicio
        }, function (evt) {
            // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
            var notify = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
            defer.notify(notify);
        });

    //cada respuesta es empaquetada en una promesa que sera enviada al controlador
// usando defer.resolve(), defer.reject(), defer.notify() y retornando defer.promise
    return defer.promise;
}

service.fileUpload = fileUpload;
return service;

}]);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUploadService', function ($scope, fileUploadService, $timeout) {
$scope.uploadPic = function (file) {
    //En el controlador esperamos la respuesta asincrona, y de acuerdo a:
    //success, error, notify, actualizamos las variables de nuestro scope.
    fileUploadService.fileUpload(file, $scope.username).then(
        success,
        error,
        notify)
}
function success(data) {
    $scope.picFile.result = data;
}

function error(msg) {
    $scope.errorMsg = msg;
}

function notify(data) {
    $scope.picFile.progress = data;
}
}]);
```